# Get email parameters

Tags: android, email

Is it possible to query an android phone programatically to get the smtp parameters: server address, password, username, etc?
I have an application which uses the javax.mail package modified for android. I would like to use these parameters to send mail programatically, without user interaction.  I can see where this could be a security hole, and therefore not allowed, but it never hurts to ask:)